# Return JavaScript class value instead of object reference

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there is a way to return a JS class's value by default instead of of reference to the class object itself. Let's say, for example, I want to wrap a string..

```
var StringWrapper = function(string) {
    this.string = string;
};

StringWrapper.prototype.contains = function (string) {
    if (this.string.indexOf(string) >= 0)
        return true;
    return false;
};

var myString = new StringWrapper("hey there");

if(myString.contains("hey"))
   alert(myString); // should alert "hey there"

if(myString == "hey there") // should be true
   doSomething();
```

and now I want to get `string` just by using `myString` rather than `myString.string`. Is this doable somehow?

### Edit

I took the `console.log(myString)` out of the question, because `console.log` has behavior that I didn't originally take into account. This question isn't about `log`.

Comment: means do you want to get that value in `console.log` ??

Comment: Do you really have to use the `new MyClass()` construct? It sounds like a "normal" function would work better.

Comment: something like: `var value = new MyClass("hey there").value;`

Comment: _"and now I want to get `value` just by using `classObj`"_ What kind of "using" are you talking about? What is it that you really want to do? If all you want is the value of `.value`, then why are you creating an object at all?

Comment: It's just a little example to illustrate the question

Comment: We get that it's just an example, but based on that example you'd be better off using just a simple function to return the value, or if that doesn't work for you then the example doesn't really represent your *actual* problem so it's very hard to say what you actually need.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. Unless you directly access the value  after you inherit from MyClass - then calling classObj alone will only return the oject as opposed to the value. Its funny how everyone gets bent out of shape when you clearly posted a simple object and inherited from it as an example.

Comment: @Andy What is a little example? You haven't given us any example of what you want to do.

Comment: I'll update and see if I can make it more reasonable

Comment: @drxw: Your comment doesn't make a lot of sense. And no one is bent out of shape. We're asking for clarification because the solution can change based on what is ultimately needed. Nothing in the example inherits from `MyClass` nor from `classObj`.

Comment: I'm not bent out of shape either, just sayin' I'll update to try to make a better question (it's updated now)

Comment: @Andy An object can't be itself and something else at the same time. In the case of strings, there is a special way that objects can be coerced into strings (as my answer shows). Please see my answer, and if that doesn't answer your question, please show us a use case that my answer wouldn't solve.

Comment: You're again stopping short of showing the most important part... an example that shows the circumstance in which you actually need to get the string value... or is it truly just for logging to the console?

Comment: @squint I don't have a real world example of this, I simply wanted to know if it were possible. There's no grander problem I'm currently trying solve with this.

Comment: @Andy, in case with `string` privimites (from yout sample) - it not same that custom class

Comment: @Andy: Then there can be no real answer. For some situations adding a `toString()` will work, for others it won't. Questions need to be specific to an actual problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question doesn't entirely make sense, but it kind of sounds like you want to implement the `.toString` interface:

```js
var MyClass = function(value) {
  this.value = value;
};

MyClass.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.value;
};


var classObj = new MyClass("hey there");

snippet.log(classObj);
snippet.log(classObj + "!");
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

With ES6 class syntax:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    toString() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

var classObj = new MyClass("hey there");

console.log(classObj);
console.log(classObj + "!");
```

Comment: Although this completely answers the question, it is still makes no sense whatsoever lol. Creating an object to wrap an string, to use the toString interface to get the string back.

Comment: @ikaros45 It doesn't make sense in this very simplistic case, but it could make sense if the object contained other stuff and that _might_ be what OP is trying to get at.

Comment: You may be right sir, if what he intends is something like an __repr__ in python, ie a representation of the object, that is ok... but from the question I would not say so.

Comment: Implementing the custom `toString` method is perfect, that's all I was looking to do - I just didn't quite know that's what I was looking to do. :D

Comment: Most of the time, most of the people mostly don't know what they are looking (includes me of course) :)

Comment: Any idea on how to do this same thing but in ES6?

Comment: @goJohnnyGo To do the same thing in ES6 you can use exactly the same code. :) But if you're asking about ES6 class syntax, I've added an example above.

Comment: @JLRishe derp. Yeah I started to play in a repl and figured it out. But thanks for adding the ES6 example. :D