# Return JavaScript class value instead of object reference (in ES6)

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I'm looking to create a class so that it will return a value instead of the class object in ES6.

It's pretty much the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371065/return-javascript-class-value-instead-of-object-reference) but in ES6. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980996/return-a-value-other-than-the-class-in-es6) touches on it a little bit, but you still have to explicitly call a property.

I want to do something like:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;  // returns an object other than *this*.
  }
}    

var foo = new Foo(4);
console.log(foo) // 4
```

But currently it returns `{value: 4}`.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this? That doesn't seem to make sense. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: foo is an object, not a primitive type, if you need to get just a value use a regular `var value`

Comment: If you don't want to create something that looks like a class, just use a function that returns a value. Why create a class if you don't want a class!

Comment: I'm creating a currency class. So it needs to retain a float value and return a string value. For example, 4.5689 and "$4.57". I've already created a library to do this in with helper functions. I just wanted to take ES6 classes for a test drive. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`valueOf` may help you with whatever it is you are trying to do:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(value) {        this.value = value; }
  valueOf()          { return this.value;         }
  ^^^^^^^^^
}    

var foo = new Foo(4);
console.log(+foo) // 4
```

You have to make sure you understand how `valueOf` works. According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf):

> JavaScript calls the valueOf method to convert an object to a primitive value.

So simply referring to the object will not invoke `valueOf`, of course; that would leave you with no way to reference the underlying object. It is used in situations where it is necessary to *coerce the object into a primitive*, such as in `+foo`.

`valueOf` has nothing to do with ES6 per se; it is available for all objects.